# Play sound on iPhone without resources

Tags: iphone

I want to play the sounds in iphone without calling them from resources.

My problem was i copied the project on the desktop changed the project name and installed it on the iphone simulator but it was not picking the new sound files it was still playing the sounds of old project can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

I just want to change the images and sounds in application not want to build a new application for every time when I want to replace images and sounds.

Best regards,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy and Rename (change bundle ID and name as well)
2. Build Menu --> Clean all Targets
3. Build and Run
4. ???
5. Profit